# multiply textbox value by label and dynamically populate the result in another textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have two textboxes and a hidden label.
Normally I do this with asp.net:

After a user enters the number in the first `textboxt1`, then after clicking the button `getprice` the system multiply the `textbox1` value by the hidden label number and show the result in the `textbox2` and vice versa.

But I want to achieve this same thing without using a button postback by using either jquery or angularjs.
As the user is typing the figures on the `textbox1`, the system should be multiplying that value at runtime and showing it in `textbox2` on keypress.

I need a function to this please.

I have tried using this jQuery... Its not working.
I want the function to have a name, so I can put on keypress on `textbox1`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#<%=Textbox.ClientID%>").bind("input", function() {
      var value1 = $("#<%=Textbox.ClientID%>").val()
      var value2 = $("#<%=HiddenTextbox2.ClientID%>").val();
      $("#<%=Textbox3.ClientID%>").val(value1 * value2);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you set on using JQuery? JavaScript can handle that function just fine.

Comment: please anyone either javascript or jquery...

Comment: In that case, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be easier just to answer using JavaScript. Here's a function that would work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MultiplyByHidden() {
        var value1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("<%=Textbox.ClientId%>").value)
        var value2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("<%=HiddenTextbox2.ClientId%>").value)
        var total = value1 * value2 
        document.getElementById("<%=Textbox3.ClientId%>").value = total
    }
</script>
```

This function does everything you are looking for and doesn't require importing of extra libraries like JQuery to handle such simple functionality.

*Edit* I forgot that it would multiply strings too.

Comment: It will try to multiply strings too... Even in vanilla JS. jQuery isn't the problem. OP problem is variable type.

Comment: hey wenadin, i just used your function, as i was inserting the figures in textbox1, the textbox2 was showing me this "NAN". do you know whats wrong?

Comment: NaN stands for Not a Number. Looks like something is going wrong with the multiplication. The same result happens if you put something in there that is non numeric or if parseFloat isn't being run on the value. Try opening up the developer tools (F12) on the page and checking the values contained in value1 and value2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to multiply strings...

The use of [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/parseInt) or [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/parseFloat) is recommanded for numbers in text inputs ;)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#<%=Textbox.ClientID%>").on("input", function() {
      var value1 = parseFloat( $("#<%=Textbox.ClientID%>").val() );
      var value2 = parseFloat( $("#<%=HiddenTextbox2.ClientID%>").val() );
      $("#<%=Textbox3.ClientID%>").val(value1 * value2);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: i just used your function, as i was inserting the figures in textbox1, the textbox2 was showing me this "NAN". do you know whats wrong?

Comment: NAN means "Not A Number"... Try to console.log the value if you are unsure what it is... You may need to remove the characters in font of the number you wish to have. Sadly, The number as to be at the beginning of the string. So `parseFloat("10.50$")` => 10.5 but `parseFloat("£10.50")` => NAN

Answer (score 0):

$("#pay,#pre").keyup(function () {

```
$('#pay').val($('#pay').val() * $('#pre').val());
```

});

> Blockquote